# Client authentication using certificates in spring without spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm trying to create cert based client authentication using spring 5, without spring boot. Is there a good tutorial on how to do it? (For example: how to specify a truststore, etc...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up not using spring security, because I did not need many things it provides, and instead used a simple filter, that checks the data of the used certificate (I also configured the application server used, to allow that certificate).

Comment: Good followup. Please review both the question and answer and see if there is more detail that you would want if you faced the same problem and were searching Stack Overflow for an answer.